# Ionic Storage : Strange behavior?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I try to use the Ionic Storage module to store some values, for example my authentication token :

```
/**
   * Get Token
   */
  public get token(): string {
    this.storage.get(this.LS_TOKEN).then((val) => {
      console.log(val);
      this._token.next(val);
      console.log( this._token.getValue());
    });

    return this._token.getValue();
    // return 'testtttt';
  }
```

I try multiple things, return directly the value, set the value and return the variable... 
But I always got a `null`, and the thing that is strange is that if I return a string directly it works, when I `console.log` the `val` it show the string that I want, but the return is always null..

What am I doing wrong ?

Edit :

In response of the first answer I have tried this :

```
/**
   * Get Token
   */
  public get token() {
    this.tokenPromise().then(yourToken => {
      console.log(yourToken);
      return yourToken;
    });
  }

  public tokenPromise() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.storage.get(this.LS_TOKEN).then((val) => {
        resolve(val);
      }).catch(ex => {
        reject(ex);
      });
    });
  }
```

My problem is the same, in my components when I try to use : `console.log(this.sharedService.token);`

It's still null

Comment: please show your storage.set method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not working with your new token() method.
It is still asnychron. Im gonna show you:

```
public get token() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        this.storage.get(this.LS_TOKEN).then((val) => {
            resolve(val);
        }).catch(ex=>{
            reject(ex);
        });
    });
}
```

Now you can use your token from the sharedservice like this:

```
this.sharedService.token.then(token=>{
    //use token here;
});
```

or you can use await, but the function who is calling it, must be async:

```
async useTokenFromService(){
    let token = await this.sharedService.token;
    console.log(token);
}
```

Comment: The thing is that in my shared service I have multiples values like the token, and sometimes I need to get like 4-5 values, it's annoying to make a `then` for each values and in each components where I need them

Comment: @Jessydan then make your method which gets all 4-5 values async and use await for the token, like in my last example

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a Promise from the storage.get() method.
This means it is running asynchron.
You can return Promise.

```
public get token() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        this.storage.get(this.LS_TOKEN).then((val) => {
            resolve(val);
        }).catch(ex=>{
            reject(ex);
        });
    });
}
```

And you can receive this with an async function and await the result:

```
async loadToken(){
   let loadedToken = await this.token();
   // use your loadedToken here...
}
```

Or you can use the .then method from the promise like this:

```
loadToken(){
    this.token().then(yourToken=>{
        // use the token yourToken here...
    });
}
```

Comment: Is this possible to make just one function who return the token string directly ?